# Determine number of leaf nodes in tree vs. non-leaf nodes

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, decision-tree

I have a dictionary which contains subdictionaries. It's a decision tree with nodes, some leaf nodes and some non-leaf nodes. How can I count each of these given the dictionary?

For example:

```py
{'Outlook': {'Overcast': 'Yes', 'Rain': {'Wind': {'Strong': 'No', 'Weak': 'Yes'}}, 'Sunny': {'Humidity': {'High': 'No', 'Normal': 'Yes'}}}}
```

This generates a tree like below:

[image]

In it are three non-leaf nodes and five leaf nodes. I have a general idea of how I can do it:

```py
def count(d):
  a, b = 0, 0 # non-leaf nodes and leaf nodes
  for key, value in d.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
      a += 1
      # some recursive call on value
    else:
      b+= 1
  return a, b
```

But I'm not sure how to organize the recursive call. Is there a built-in method?

Comment: not sure if i've misunderstood but should dicts return `(x := count(value))[0] +1, x[1]` and non-dicts return `a, b+1`?

Comment: Just to clarify: how do you want a, b to handled during recursion? Do you want an a, b for each level, or do just want a total of a, b for the entire recursion?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the fact that the keys of root dict are branches and values of the root dict are new nodes. Rest is simple I have given my code below with the correct output 3, 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
def get_count(d, c = {0:0, 1:0}):
    c[0]+=1    #count non-leaf nodes
    nodes = d.keys()
    for node in nodes:
      subnodes = d[node].values()
      for subnode in subnodes:
          if isinstance(subnode, dict)           
              get_count(subnode,c)
          else:
              c[1]+=1  #count leaf nodes

    return c




d = {'Outlook': {'Overcast': 'Yes', 'Rain': {'Wind': {'Strong': 'No', 'Weak': 'Yes'}}, 'Sunny': {'Humidity': {'High': 'No', 'Normal': 'Yes'}}}}

print(get_count(d))
```

> Output : 3,5
>
> 3 : no of non-leaf nodes
>
> 5 : no. of leaf nodes

Comment: I see what you mean. Count the subnodes and values of current node, then recurse into each subnode.

Comment: Exactly. The tricky part here is the branches represented in the dictionary as keys within the root. We dont need to count these branches. Rest is simple. Don't forget to mark as answered if it helped you.

Comment: Like d["Outlook"].keys() will give you branches from the Outlook node and d[branch].values() will give further nodes from that branch

Answer (score 3):

You can do simply

```py
def count(d):
  a, b = 0, 0 # subdicts and not-subdicts
  for key, value in d.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
      a += 1
      suba, subb = count(value)
      a += suba
      b += subb
    else:
      b += 1
  return a, b
```

However, your example has five "non-dictionaries" and five "dictionaries."

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to create a running dictionary that stores the counts:

```
def get_count(d, c):
  for a, b in d.items():
    c[isinstance(b, dict)] += 1
    if isinstance(b, dict):
       get_count(b, c)


d = {'Outlook': {'Overcast': 'Yes', 'Rain': {'Wind': {'Strong': 'No', 'Weak': 'Yes'}}, 'Sunny': {'Humidity': {'High': 'No', 'Normal': 'Yes'}}}}
c = {0:0, 1:0}
get_count(d, c)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{0: 5, 1: 5}
#0: elements, #1: sub-dictionaries
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect since he has specifically asked for the number of leaf nodes and non-leaf nodes. Output should be 3,5.